# apache pig unable to perform grouping and counting

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am kind of newbie for Pig scripting . Please help me out with this issue.
I have no clue as to where I am going wrong.

My data

```
(catA,myid_1,2014,store1,appl)
(catA,myid_2,2014,store1,milk)
(catA,myid_3,2014,store1,appl)
(catA,myid_4,2014,store1,milk)
(catA,myid_5,2015,store1,milk)
(catB,myid_6,2014,store2,milk)
(catB,myid_7,2014,store2,appl)
```

**The below is the result expected**

```
(catA,2014,milk,2)
(catA,2014,apple,2)
(catA,2015,milk,1)
(catB,2014,milk,1)
(catB,2014,apple,1)
```

Need to count the number of food item based on the category,year.
below is my pig script

```
list = LOAD 'shop' USING PigStorage(',') AS (category:chararray,id:chararray,mdate:chararray,my_store:chararray,item:chararray);
list_of = FOREACH list GENERATE category,SUBSTRING(mdate,0,4) as my_date,my_store,item;
StoreG = GROUP list_of BY (category,my_date,my_store);
result = FOREACH StoreG
{
food_list = FOREACH list_of GENERATE item;
food_count = DISTINCT food_list;
GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (category,my_date,my_store),COUNT(food_count);
 }
DUMP result;
```

My output for the above script is below

```
(catA,2014,store1,2)
(catA,2015,store1,1)
(catB,2014,store2,2)
```

Could anyone please let me know as to where I am wrong in my script 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it.Not the most elegant but working example:

```
list = LOAD 'shop' USING PigStorage(',') AS (category:chararray,id:chararray,mdate:chararray,my_store:chararray,item:chararray);

list_of = FOREACH list GENERATE category,SUBSTRING(mdate,0,4) AS my_date,my_store,item;

StoreG = GROUP list_of BY (category,my_date,my_store,item);

result = FOREACH StoreG GENERATE 
      group.category AS category,
      group.my_date AS my_date,
      group.my_store AS mys_store,
      group.item AS item, 
      COUNT(list_of.item) AS nb_items;

DUMP result;
```

When we add alias *item* to the `GROUP BY` statement is basically the same as to find distinct items and then count them(as you already did in the parenthesis).

If you still want to use your code you simply add a relation `food_list.item` to the code below :

```
result = FOREACH StoreG
{
food_list = FOREACH list_of GENERATE item;
food_count = DISTINCT food_list;
GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (category,my_date,my_store),food_list.item,COUNT(food_count);
 }
```

Comment: Your code worked ! Thanks a lot mate. I have really no clue as to why I am not able to reason like you ! could it be my experience . I am new to the world of scripting and sql like query. will pick it up. thanks once again

Comment: Yep, just a matter of experience.  Here is an ok start http://joshualande.com/cube-rollup-pig-data-science/

Answer (score 0):

```
StoreG = GROUP list_of BY (category,my_date,my_store);
```

should be

```
StoreG = GROUP list_of BY (category,my_date,item);
```

since your expected results are grouping by item not store.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your input , assume if I want a output like (catA,2014, store ,milk,2) . Meaning I would like to see the store along with the final result. what should I add to the script ?

Comment: you can do StoreG = GROUP list_of BY (category,my_date,my_store,item);

Comment: after executing the result is   (catA,2014,store1,appl,1)
(catA,2014,store1,milk,1)
(catA,2015,store1,milk,1)
(catB,2014,store2,appl,1)
(catB,2014,store2,milk,1)

Comment: please refer the question above for the expected results.